# Generic Method to create multiple types

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to write a method that works sort of like this:

```
public class BaseClass {}
public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass {}
public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass {}

public class BaseClassCreator
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        if( T is DerivedClass1 ) return new DerivedClass1();
        if( T is DerivedClass2 ) return new DerivedClass2();

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting compiler errors saying I can not converted DerivedClass1 to T. How do I need to write this method to do the following:

```
BaseClass x = BaseClassCreator.Create<DerivedClass1>();
BaseClass y = BaseClassCreator.Create<DerivedClass2>();
```

Comment: Also, wouldnt this be a whole lot easier if you did  return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) ?

Comment: Is your real code that simple? If it is then you're not really doing anything the `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` method doesn't do.

Comment: Not that simple. It was just to demonstrate the error I was getting.

Comment: CodeInChaos is right; this looks like an abuse of generics. If the factory can create only n kinds of things then it is not *generic*, so do not make it a *generic factory*. Make a factory with n different CreateDerived1, CreateDerived2, etc, methods.

Comment: @EricLippert I was just doing this out of curiosity. I realize it is an abuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` (and `as`) keywords operate on instances, not types. Im guessing what you actually wanted was

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(DerivedClass1)) ....
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case where you could just leverage the `new()` constraint

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : BaseClass, new()
{
  return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `a is T` only works if the left side is an instance, not a type. So you need to apply `typeof(T)` on both sides. And then either use `==` if you want to check if the types are identical, or `IsAssignableFrom(...)` to check if one is derived from the other. In Your case you probably want `==`.

The casts only work if you insert a known base type. Which can be `object` or `BaseClass`.

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : BaseClass
{
    if( typeof(T) == typeof(DerivedClass1 )) return (T)(BaseClass)new DerivedClass1();
    if( typeof(T) == typeof(DerivedClass2 )) return (T)(BaseClass)new DerivedClass2();

    return null;
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good idea in the first place. This code isn't really generic since it only works for a few classes you hardcoded.